# Autoscaling y-axis using set_ylim(auto = True) doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to auto-scale the y-axis for different boxplots corresponding to different columns in my dataframe. The dataframe has 19 columns with the last column being 'class' which is a categorical variable with 3 values. I've tried the code below but the result is not what I had expected.
Thanks for your help!

Code:

```
axes = data.boxplot(by='class',figsize = (10,10), return_type='axes')
for ax in axes.values:
    ax.set_ylim(auto=True)
    plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: could you please include all the matplotlib code you use to generate the figure?

Comment: Seems the axes are shared. So due to the `scaled_variance.1` plot it goes up to 1000. If you expect different limits for individual plots you would also need to have each one with its own ticks and labels. So it might be best to create them individually from the start.

Comment: @norok2 that is all of the matplotlib code I have used to generate the figure, is there anything else that might aid you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ah alright,I was hoping there might be faster way than creating 18 individual boxplots. Thanks!

Comment: @MashedPotatoes As already noted you seems to be using shared axes, I wanted to check that.

Comment: This worked for me: I put `ax.set_ylim(auto=True)` before `ax.plot(...)`.